# Sqoop job dependencies

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Can I configure two sqoop command so that they are dependent on each other? Like if the first sqoop job is successful, second gets triggered. If first fails, second should not run

Comment: Sure. You can use oozie for creating the workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use oozie for this. Create an oozie workflow. Execute the second action only if the first action succeeds.